# Using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadSections cause Tableview Cell to flicker

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to use either `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` or `reloadSections` to reload a particular tableView cell when a segmented switch within that cell has changed (which in turn changed the display in the `UIScrollView` within that cell). Using this causes the last tableView cell (not related to the reloaded cell) to flicker: the background of the cell changes to a black color briefly. This last tableView cell is different from the other, as it is contains a `UICollectionView` (see the picture below). All cells in the tableView are clear, with the `backgroundView` governing the background color gradient.

```
//tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath 
case .cellToReload:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("graphs", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WeatherTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            let segmentControl = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UISegmentedControl
            segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segment
            segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
            cell.graph.delegate = self
            cell.graph.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            if segment == 0 || segment == 1 {
                cell.graph.contentSize.width = cell.frame.width * 2.0
            } else {
                cell.graph.contentSize.width = cell.frame.width
            }
            cell.graph.contentSize.height = cell.graph.frame.height
            let ConditionsView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, cell.graph.contentSize.width, cell.graph.contentSize.height))
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        switch (segment) {
            //create new view and add as a subview to cell.graph

case .flickeringCell:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("weeklyWeatherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WeatherTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.forecastCollectionView.delegate = self
    cell.forecastCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.forecastCollectionView.reloadData()
    cell.forecastCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.forecastCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.forecastCollectionView.backgroundView = cell.backgroundView
    cell.forecastCollectionView.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor
    return cell


func segmentAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let path = NSIndexSet(index: 1)
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        segment = 0
        tableView.reloadSections(path, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case 1:
        segment = 1
        tableView.reloadSections(path, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case 2:
        segment = 2
        tableView.reloadSections(path, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        break
    }
    
}

//Table background
func createGradientForTable {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    ...
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sender.tableView.frame)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
    sender.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

TableView cell with the UICollectionView:

[image]

Comment: You should probably set the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` to clear as well.

Comment: I notice the view heirarchy has something called "Visual Effect View". Are you applying some sort of transform/effect on that view?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I actually solved my problem my removing that Visual Effect View and implement the same effect by adding a background to the collectionView. It was the Visual Effect View that was flickering and not the cell or the other views within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed that Visual Effect View and implement the same effect by adding a background to the collectionView. It was the Visual Effect View that was flickering and not the cell or the other views within it. I achieved the same affect as the Visual Effect View by editing:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

to include:

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember when updating UI to dispatch and async task on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    } 
}
```